# How to read a file line by line in php and compare it with an existing string?

Tags: php, string, file, search

I tried to write this program to compare a user-name in a file with an entered user-name to check whether it exists, but the program doesn't seem to work. Please help. The program was supposed to open a file called allusernames to compare the usernames. If the user name was not found, add it to the file.

```
<?php
    $valid=1;
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $listofusernames = fopen("allusernames.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open");
    while(!feof($listofusernames)) {
        $cmp = fgets($listofusernames);
        $val = strcmp($cmp , $username);

        if($val == 0) {
            echo ("Choose another user name, the user name you have entered has already been chosen!");
            $valid=0;
            fclose($listofusernames);
            break;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }

    if($valid != 0) {
        $finalusers = fopen("allusernames.txt", "a+");
        fwrite($finalusers, $username.PHP_EOL);
        fclose($finalusers);
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: I ran the code but it accepted the user-names that already existed.

Comment: Isn't this the sort of things relational databases are meant to handle? If there's no particular reason you must use a file, why not use a database instead

Comment: I am not well versed with databases yet. I wanted to test this with file.

Comment: How are the user names entered in the file? Are they each on a separate line? Or is it a CSV?

Comment: They are on a separate line.

Comment: Use regex.. $user=file_get_contents("foo.txt");
if(preg_match_all("@^username$@i",$user))
{echo "exists";}
else {echo "doesnt exist";}

Comment: just var_dump both variables in strcmp function so you can visually see the difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to replace linefeed/newline character from each line to compare.

```
while(!feof($listofusernames)) {
    $cmp = fgets($listofusernames);
    $cmp = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '',$cmp);
    $val = strcmp($cmp , $username);
    if($val == 0) {
        echo ("Choose another user name, the user name you have entered has already been chosen!");
        $valid=0;
        fclose($listofusernames);
        break;
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}
```

i have added following line in you code

```
  $cmp = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '',$cmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

I havent tested this but I wonder if you could use something like

```
<?php

$user = $_POST["username"];

$contents = file_get_contents("allusernames.txt");
$usernames = explode("\n",$contents);

if(in_array($user,$usernames))
{
    echo "Choose another username";
}
else
{
    $contents .= "\n".$user;
    file_put_contents("allusernames.txt",$contents);
}
```

I think things like file get contents etc. need a certain version of PHP but they do make things a lot nicer to work with.

This also assumes that your usernames are seperated by new lines.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do this more simple with this code:

```
<?php
$username = $_POST["username"];
$listofusernames = 'allusernames.txt';

$content = file($listofusernames);

if(in_array($username, $content)) {
    echo ("Choose another user name, the user name you have entered has already been chosen!");
} else {
    $content[] = $username . PHP_EOL;
    file_put_contents($listofusernames, implode('', $content));
}

?>
```